# remove unicode formated japanese strings from python output

Tags: python, unicode, substring

I have a script that gathers some text elements from the web; the content in question is machine translated and leaves some remnants in a mix of the original language and english. I would like to strip out any non latin characters but I haven't been able to find a good sub to do so. Here is an example of the string and desired output: I want to remove this: `\u30e6\u30fc\u30ba\u30c9` but keep everything else. >> I want to remove this: but keep everything else.

here is my current code to demonstrate the problem

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from pprint import pprint
import os
import re
import logging

header = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36', 'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8', 'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.8', 'Cookie' : 'search_layout=grid; search.ab=test-A' }
# necesary to perform the http get request

def main():
    # get page content
    response = requests.get('http://global.rakuten.com/en/store/wanboo/item/w690-3/', headers=header)
    # return parsed body for the lxml module to process
    parsed_body = html.fromstring(response.text)
    # get the title tag
    dirtyname = unicode(parsed_body.xpath("//h1[contains(@class, 'b-ttl-main')]/text()"))
    # test that this tag returns undesired unicode output for the japanese characters
    print dirtyname
    # attempt to clean the unicode using a custom filter to remove any characters in this paticular range
    clean_name = ''.join(filter(lambda character:ord(character) < 0x3000, unicode(dirtyname)))
    # output of the filter should return no unicode characters but currently does not
    print clean_name
    # the remainder of the script is uncessary for the problem in question so I have removed it

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
''.join(filter(lambda character:ord(character) < 0x3000,my_unicode_string))
```

I think would work ...

or maybe you want to limit it byte size characters

```
 ''.join(filter(lambda character:ord(character) < 0xff,my_unicode_string))
```

basically its pretty easy to filter out any ranges you want ... (realistically its probably safe to filter out `codepoint < 0x100`)

for example

```
>>> test_text = u'\u30e62\u30fcX\u30ba\u30c9T'
>>> ''.join(filter(lambda character:ord(character) < 0x3000,test_text))
u'2XT'
```

with respect to your problem as linked in your question

```
dirtyname = parsed_body.xpath() ... #this returns a list ... not a string so we will put out own list as a stand in to demonstrate the issue


dirtyname = [u"hello\u2345world"]
```

you were then calling unicode on that list

```
dirtyname = unicode(dirtyname)
```

now if you were to print the repr as I suggested in my comment you would see

```
>>> print repr(dirtyname)
u'[u"Hello\\u2345world"]' 
>>> for item in dirtyname:
...    print item
[
u
"
H
#and so on
```

notice now it is just a string ... it is not a list and there is no unicode characters in the string,since the backslash is escaped

you can easily fix this, by simply getting the element in the array rather than the whole array .... `parsed_body.xpath(...)[0]`

```
>>> dirtyname = parsed_body.xpath("//h1[contains(@class, 'b-ttl-main')]/text()")[0]
>>> #notice that we got the unicode element that is in the array
>>> print repr(dirtyname)
u"Hello\u2345world"
>>> cleanname =  ''.join(filter(lambda character:ord(character) < 0x3000, dirtyname))
>>> print repr(clean_name)
u"Helloworld" 
>>> #notice that everything is correctly filtered
```

Comment: running the first one on the parsed content returns: ord() expected a character, but string of length 135 found

Comment: then you are nto giving it a string ... but rather a list of strings (maybe a list of a single string) .. .see my edit for proof that this works ...

Comment: You're right, it was a list containing one string. I used unicode() to convert it then applied your character filter but the resulting string remains exactly the same as the original. My example comes from an lxml and python-requests parse of live html content if that is relevant. Here is the site in question: http://global.rakuten.com/en/store/wanboo/item/w690-3/. The item title is the object that is being parsed by lxml and requests. Thanks in advance for your time and expertise.

Comment: Im guessing your converting it to utf8 somehow ... and then this will break because every utf8 ordinal is under a byte (sort of) ... if you want to do something like `print repr(my_unicode_string)` it will probably show abunch of `\x##` ... instead of `\u####`  , maybe you could run that command and put it in a codepad post or something I could look at the actual string, since the example string you gave works fine I have to assume your text doesnt actually represent internally as unicode...

Comment: Here is the test script that produces the output that I'm trying to filter. I've omitted unnecessary methods and imports for simplicity. Thanks again for the assist: http://bpaste.net/show/rs4h2I1gFbwWRBu8KO8l/

Comment: Updated bare bones version with comments: http://bpaste.net/show/ZBnudR3rPa52dGE7mAtp/

Comment: Thanks a ton Joran, very informative and effective fix for what was a big issue.

Comment: Update on this issue Joran: when I tried to put this into my production code I found that this filter breaks for various characters. I get a great deal of these type of errors: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u203b' in position 769: ordinal not in range(128). How could I increase the range that is being filtered to cover the majority of the japanese language. Thanks in advance for all of your help. BTW I come from ruby but IMO python is great thus far.